# Javascript - how to toggle all next singlings until class found

Tags: javascript

I have the table below which hides all the `child` rows by default.

I'd like to toggle all child rows right underneath the corresponding clicked `root` row. That is, the `n` `.child` rows next to the clicked `.root`.  How can I do this in pure Javascript?

```css
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="func(this)">Root</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="func(this)">Root</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>Child 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, what you want to do is to remove the `hidden` classname from all the rows after the clicked one until you get to a row that is not hidden, then you can do this:

```
function func(root) {
    var row = root.parentNode.parentNode;
    row = nextElement(row, "tr");
    while (row && row.className === "hidden") {
        row.className = "";
        row = nextElement(row, "tr");
    }

}

function nextElement(start, tag) {
    tag = tag.toUpperCase();
    start = start.nextSibling;
    while (start) {
        if (start.tagName === tag) {
            return start;
        } else {
            start = start.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dvg6j9or/

---

Here's another version that works off the array of rows and uses a parent search to find the right level of the table:

```
function func(root) {
    var table = findParentTag(root, "table");
    var currentRow = findParentTag(root, "tr");
    var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(table.querySelectorAll("tr"));
    var currentIndex = rows.indexOf(currentRow) + 1;
    // now traverse rows until you find one that is different than the starting row
    for (; currentIndex < rows.length; ++currentIndex) {
        if (rows[currentIndex].className.indexOf("hidden") !== -1) {
            rows[currentIndex].className = "";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

}

function findParentTag(start, tag) {
    tag = tag.toUpperCase();
    while (start && start.tagName !== tag) {
        start = start.parentNode;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hut56fLg/

Comment: @SijiaDin - I added another version.